# Perl apache httpd.conf

Tags: perl, apache, config

I have inherited an apache sever instance that runs a perl application. I found this directive in the httpd.conf.

```
<perl>
use lib qw(
    /relative path1
    /relative path2
);
</perl>
```

The minimal documentation I have found on this directive says that it causes all apache conf files to be written in perl. But the above code only adds lib paths to @INC. Does anyone know more about this directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: "But the above code only adds lib paths to @INC."

That is exactly what that code is supposed to do. This particular bit of code is meant to add include paths so that one can load modules (possibly using `PerlModule`) from nonstandard paths.

The `<perl>` section allows Perl code to be executed in the Apache config file instead of an external perl file. It's offered for convenience only and really doesn't give you any additional functionality beyond what the (more commone, I think) directive `PerlRequire` gives you.

To say that a `<perl>` directive "causes Apache config files to be written in Perl" does not really make sense, and it is not true. It *allows* you to do so if you *wanted*, but that is not what is being done here.

Answer (score 1):

With mod_perl, the tag allows Perl to be used/executed in a httpd config file and also provides a set of variables and methods to do the standard httpd config bits and pieces. 
http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/PerlSections.html

As for your config example, I can only assume it's trying to modify the lib path for everything running under mod_perl otherwise it doesn't make much sense on its own (unless you have more  sections in the config files?)

Check in a Perl script executed on your web host if those configured lib paths appear:

```
print join "\n", @INC;
```